# Word Break in AMP

Tags: amp-html, word-wrap, word-break

I'm trying to prevent words breaking in posts in a new AMP layout. I fixed the issue with the excerpts on the front page with this:

```
.fbp-cnt p, .fsp-cnt p {
    word-break: normal;
}
```

However, I can't seem to do the same thing within the actual post.

This is what I'm looking at:

```
.cntn-wrp {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 1.7;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

I tried changing word-wrap to normal and/or changing word-break from word-wrap to normal but nothing is having an effect.

[partyfavorz.com](https://partyfavorz.com)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it. Instead of the element targeting the whole post, I used the element from the first paragraph. Here's the code:

```
.cntn-wrp p, .cntn-wrp ul, .cntn-wrp ol {
    margin: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
    word-break: normal;
}
```